# Regex match any 2 character combinations only if contains at least 1 specified character

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match any `space` and `comma` combination as long as it contains at least 1 `comma`

**Test case**

```
"aaa,bbb    ccc ,, ddd  ,,  ,, , eee,"
```

**Results**

> "aaa`,`bbb  ccc`,,`ddd`,,  ,, ,`eee`,`"

**What i have**

```
[\s,]+(?!,)
```

However this selects spaces without commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[, ]*,[, ]*
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u46WRA/1)

**Explanation:**

- `[, ]*` - matches **0**+ occurrences of either a space or a `,`
- `,` - matches single occurrence of a `,`
- `[, ]*` - matches **0**+ occurrences of either a space or a `,`

Comment: I was going to say extra points for an explanation, great thanks!